# Adding a C wire to thermostat with oil berner and AC

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I have a oil burner for baseboard heat and forced air AC that is controlled by one thermostat. There are a total of 5 wires coming to the thermostat 2 wires from the boiler and 3 wires coming from the AC. I want to to replace the thermostat with Honeywell wifi thermostat that requires a C-wire. 
My current wire is a 5-wire. Assuming that I will be able to pull a new 6 or 7-wire to the thermostat my question is where do the connect the other end of the C-wire. 
Can I connect it to the boiler? Do I need 2 C-wires one each for boiler and AC?
[image: wiring at boiler]
[image: wiring at air handler]

The boiler is Buderus G115WS/4.. It has 3 zones. Zone 1 for first floor, zone 2 for 2nd floor and zone 3 for hot water.

A/c handler is Carrier model FX4ANF030

At the thermostat
Red -> R
Blue -> Rc
Green -> G
Yellow -> Y
White  -> W

Comment: In you situation,  it's probably going to be easier to grab `C` from the A/C. However, there's no way to say for sure, since you've told us almost nothing about your setup.   Please include make and model of all equipment, and possibly a wiring diagram showing the current wiring.

Comment: I attached pictures and updated model numbers. Hope this gives a better picture. I do see the option to connect C to the boiler zone 1. Will this work.

Comment: You should be able to connect a wire from the `C` terminal on the zone controller, to the `C` terminal on the thermostat for that zone. For example, if the new thermostat is the zone 1 thermostat. You'll connect the c wire to the zone 1 `C` terminal on the controller, and the `C` terminal on the thermostat. However, sometimes with boilers and zone controllers, things aren't always wired exactly how you'd expect.  To get a definitive answer, you'll have to include a wiring diagram that shows all the control wiring between all the equipment and thermostats.